# Database access speed on local IP vs. loopback?

Tags: mysql, performance, networking, installation

Question:

MySQL only accepts ONE IP to listen on.
So you can either do
bind-address          = 127.0.0.1
or
bind-address          = 192.168.1.125

with 192.168.1.125 being the same computer as 127.0.0.1, this is, supposed you don't want to bind to 0.0.0.0.

So if I set it to 192.168.1.125, to allow connecting to it from another computer (e.g. to administer the database, create tables, update etc), then a web application running on 192.168.1.125 will also have to connect via 192.168.1.125.

My question now is this:
Will the performance of database queries run from a web application on machine 192.168.1.125 be worse when the application connects with IP 192.168.1.125 as opposed to when it would connect as 127.0.0.1 ?

Theoretically, it would sent the query via the router back to itselfs, thus slowing performance down as opposed to the loopback interface.

So basically, is the driver/OS sophisticated enough to realize it mustn't send the data over the network, because this isn't necessary in this case ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
traceroute 192.168.1.125
```

on Linux, respectively

```
tracert 192.168.1.125
```

on Windows should give you the answer :)

Yes, the OS is sophisticated enough to not go over the network to the router, and I'm pretty sure it will also not go via the network card. If you really want to make sure there is no performance impact, the best thing is to do some small microbenchmark and compare.

Comment: 1  zotac.local (192.168.1.125)  0.094 ms  0.042 ms  0.040 ms

Comment: vs.  1  computername.local (192.168.1.126)  3.074 ms  5.942 ms  8.157 m for non-local

Comment: Ironically, localhost is in average 0.001 ms slower than 192.168.1.125

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. Yes, the OS is sophisticated enough to realise that it does not need to use physical hardware to talk to itself
2. You don't care anyway

You don't need to set bind-address. If you don't set it, it will bind to all interfaces. This is almost definitely What You Want.

In the highly unlikely situation that you have several network connections, some of which you don't want mysql to listen on, then you need the "bind-address" command. However, I'd discourage its use if possible (use a firewall instead to prevent connections from places you don't want connections from i.e. the internet).